# CSS nested div height 100%

Tags: css

I've currently got the #border div at 100% of the page height, but am trying to get the #container div to stretch to 100% inside #border. At the moment #container only stretches to fit the content inside it.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:19px;
    color:#333333;
    background: #f5f1ec;
    text-align: left;
}

#border {
    background: #f5f1ec;
    border:solid 1px #FFFFFF; 
    width: 880px;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    padding:10px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 50px 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: sorry guys, that should have been #container in the question, not #content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved:

```
#container {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 50px 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:780px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: thanks Starx. Just completely stripped back what I was doing and this works great. Was trying to get a footer in there as well, and have the border stop before it, so might have to rework my layout. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Adding position absolute did cause the nested div to fill the full height, but it also caused it to fill MORE than the full height for me. Any idea why? I don't want scrollbars on pages that don't need them.

Comment: That is actually due to margin and padding of the body probably set them to `0` and if the problem follows try setting `overflow:hidden` in the body, it will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `#container{min-height:inherit;position:absolute;}`

and add `overflow:hidden;` to #border.

Comment: Sorry. You put #content in the description on top.

Comment: hey edl, i meant content, as in the content ( which is a standard two column blog layout)